# GPU fails on because UPS

Tags: battery, gpu, ups, windows-10-v1909

I got a new UPS not long ago, and installed it's software (upsilon 2000) and driver. the software installs a battery driver for the UPS so I can use windows power plans settings to control what happens on power failure and etc.
Since then I found out my GPU is somehow clashing with the battery driver.

It is a very long story- but after a few weeks that everything is working normally, all of the sudden windows reported that my GPU is malfunctioning and disabled it. after much research I found that users reported this issue usually on laptops due to some connection to the battery, and solved it by fixing something with the battery. this hit home because the newly installed UPS and battery-driver installed. 
I disabled the battery device/driver from the device manager, reboot, and the GPU starts working again.
It is important to state that the issue did not occur during a power failure or any UPS/battery communication error (at least not a visible one)

I'd like to enable the battery driver back again, However I would like to figure out first what is the connection between the GPU and battery and why they are interfering with each other. hopefully this will lead to a permanent solution that will not have my GPU disabled again by windows.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some links to the info you found on the laptops with batteries interfering with GPUs? I wasn't able to find anything. Also, any error codes you received would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Hi. sorry for the late response. I got error code 43. I can't seem to find the original posts I found involving the laptops. I did find others similar to mine: https://superuser.com/questions/1291248/gpu-power-supply-fail
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-nvidia-code-43-windows-has-stopped-this-device-because-it-has-reported-problems/

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem after installing UpSilon 2000. After reboot, my graphics card (Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 on Win10 64Bit PC) stopped working, and graphics processing defaulted to a crude Microsoft generic driver.

I first did a full de-installation (with internet disconnected) + clean installation of the graphics card. This did not help.

Then I disabled the Mega Battery driver on the Device Manager and rebooted. Full operation of the graphics card was restored. UPS stopping must now be set to "Use UPSilon to stop". i.e. not via the computer's ACPI.